# Создать пачку записей в MySQL

Tags: postgresql, mysql

Каким образом можно создать множество записей в `mysql/postgres` ?
Написать сценарий `php` не катит: количество записей, которое требуется создать - несколько лямов.
Просто иногда возникает желание протестировать ту или иную фишку в базе, для этого требуется много записей, содержимое которых не так важно.
Есть какой-то аналог `fill_array`?

UPD:
Нашел [способ через процедуры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766282/how-can-i-fill-my-mysql-tables-with-test-data-of-about-100-000-records). Что наталкивает на мысль, что более прямого способа нет

Comment: [тут на вьюхах](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нащел [здесь](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code)

[Сделал демку](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/355e5/2)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_4k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_64k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_256 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_1m
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 16 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_64k lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE TABLE testme (id int ,txt varchar(255));

INSERT INTO testme (SELECT n,"test text" from generator_1m where n<100000) ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from testme limit 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/355e5/2/0)**:

```
| ID |       TXT |
------------------
|  0 | test text |
|  1 | test text |
|  2 | test text |
|  3 | test text |
|  4 | test text |
```

Comment: Ну, у меня получилось 
insert into table ... select from table запустить несколько раз. Очевидно, количество записей растет приблизительно как степень двойки, так что результат нагоняется достаточно быстро.

Надо сравнить по скорости с этим, спасибо. =)
Вот что тут много лучше - четкое количество добавляемых записей.

Comment: польза в таком подходе несомненна. данные генерируеются только один раз, без предварительной заливки куда-либо. примерно такого же результата можно достичь с помощью cross join'а. взять эти 16 записей и сделать много раз cross join с самой собой. но тут изящнее подход, конечно. +1

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> The `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.

Comment: тут тоже есть проблема - бастрое заполнение файла. Но таки да, это должно быть быстрее, чем через запросы.