# Подскажите тяжелые  SQL запросы

Tags: sql, mysql

Для отладки и тестирования приложения нуждаюсь в вызове подобных запросов.
Может у Вас на примете есть парочка вариантов.
Что я только не делал:
LIKE,COUNT(*) ,SELECT * GROUP BY... Когда нужно так все запросы вроде идеальны.

Comment: ваша база не обязана выполнять любой запрос быстро. она обязана выполнять любой *используемый вами* запрос быстро. если на ваших запросах все идеально, значит все и так хорошо. проверьте на разных объемах данных 10^n, где n от 5 до 8, скажем. если будет деградация производительности, вы это увидите...

Comment: Попробуйте внести в базу миллиард записей, где есть поле text, внесите в него много текста и попробуйте поискать запросом. При этом не используйте индексы, при этом ещё соедините эту таблицу с какой-нибудь другой таблицей, где тоже миллиард записей :D

Comment: ИДЕЯ.Но как лучше записать жтот милиард записей?Через load file?

Comment: Вы сначала сто тысяч запишите и время замерьте.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/232233#232540

Comment: и вообще, [CROSS JOIN][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#CROSS_JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232233#232540

ну и сделайте запрос из той таблицы

```
select t.id,t1.id as id1 from testme t inner join testme t1 on t.id+sin(t1.id)=t1.id+cos(t.id) limit 50;
```

Comment: Месье знает толк в извращениях: джойн с синусом это сильно :)

Answer (score 1):

Уберите индексы и попробуйте любой запрос с джойном на неиндексированное поле или джойн с выражением типа LIKE - и вы получите то что хотите :)

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай соединение двух подобных вложенных запросов:

```
SELECT table1.column1 as t1_c1,
       table1.column2 as t1_c2,
       table2.column1 as t2_c1,
       table2.column2 as t2_c2
FROM table1, table2
```